# React Redux - element not rendering on page but React not throwing error

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I seem to be having an issue with my react-redux app. I'm currently using next.js, which tends to act a little weird when working with redux so i'm not sure if that's the issue. That said, I'm trying to render a component that loops through an array of objects. very simple. my mapState function is working and when I set info to `state.aboutMe[0]` i received the first value. Once I remove this and try to iterate through the array, Initially, I got an error that says "A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object." but I was able to resolve that by wrapping my my `info.map` in a `<div>` el.

I checked out the other questions and refactored my function in a class that extends the React.Component class but still no luck with iterating. In that case, it just prints nothing to the screen. I've added that code at the bottom as well. Please let me know if I can clear anything up. Thanks in advance!

```
// This code IS working
// Needed to wrap inner return statement in JSX
const heading = ({info}) => {
    console.log(info);
    return (
    <div>{
    info.map(x => {
    return ( 
      <div>
        <h2>{x.title}</h2>
      </div>
    )
    }) 
  }
    </div>
  )
  }

  // Same code without inner return 
  const heading = ({info}) => {
    console.log(info);
    return (
    <div>
      {
        info.map(x => (
          <div>
            <h2>{x.title}</h2>
          </div>
          )
        )
      }
    </div>
  )
}

// prints info in console
    const heading = ({info}) => {
   console.log(info);
  return (
    <div>{
    info.map(x => {
    <div>
      <h2>{x.title}</h2>
    </div>
    }) 
  }
    </div>
  )
}

const mapState = state => ({ info: state.aboutMe })
const Heading = connect(mapState)(heading);

// EXAMPLE WITH CLASS
// Prints nothing to the screen but doesnt throw error
class homePage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { info } = this.props;
    console.log(info);
    return (
      <div> {
      info.map(x => {
        <div>
          <h2>{x.title}</h2><p>{x.text}</p>
        </div>
      })
      }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
const mapState = state => ({ info: state.aboutMe })
const Heading = connect(mapState)(homePage);
```

Comment: Your anonymous arrow function doesn't return anything. Once you use curly-braces you lose the implicit return. It doesn't throw an error because there's no error. Unrelated, but I'd make a tiny component for the title so you end up with this: https://gist.github.com/davelnewton/1214c9bb3f7103ff3d0264a95892c999

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be

```
return (
  <div>
    {info.map(x => (<div>
      <h2>{x.title}</h2><p>{x.text}</p>
    </div>)
    )}
  </div>
)
```

because the div inside the map isn't really being returned

Comment: this is throwing an error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token`. I believe it's due to JSX having one parent element.

Comment: @ThomasGreco I've updated the code. There should be no {} inside the map function

Comment: wow! awesome, that worked. i understand what you're saying but i'm going to update the example with brackets and without so people can see.

Comment: where do i do that at ?

Comment: here. you should see a check mark at the left side of the answer.

Comment: lol yes, i meant where in this page but appreciate the clarification. got u

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly using a return inside map.